# MongoDB - include a field for calculation but remove from result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following query:

```
db.raw_iot_data.aggregate([
   {
      "$match":{
         "m.i": "cycle-time"
      }
   },
   {
      "$addFields":{
         "date":{
            "$dateFromString":{
               "dateString": "2022-03-17T01:02:24.367Z"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "t": "$$ROOT.t",
         "v": "$$ROOT.v",
         "m": "$$ROOT.m",
         "test": {
            "$cond":[
               {
                  "$gte":[
                     "$t",
                     "$date"
                  ]
               },
               1,
               0
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "m.i":"cycle-time"
      }
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "test":{
            "$eq":1
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "v":1,
         "test":0,
         "t":1
      }
   }
])
```

I'm including a `test` variable for some filtration, but then I want to remove it from the final result. This gives me `Invalid $project:: caused by :: Cannot do exclusion on a field test in inclusion projection` because I have set `test: 0` in the final aggregate.

How do I do this?

Comment: If you remove `test: 0` from the final `$project` do you get the results that you want?

Comment: @user20042973 if I remove `test: 0` then the result set would contain `test` field as well. I don't want that to be present in the final result set

Comment: Are you sure? Did you try it? [This playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wC1L1jAfoC7) (and [the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-existing-fields)) suggests that it works just fine.

Comment: Separately, most of that aggregation pipeline seems unnecessary. A single `$match` and `$project` seems to [yield the same result](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MpUelew9HnJ)

Comment: @user20042973, ya I moved the `match` after the `project`. I have two matches because I assumed it'll be faster to first do a match by the `m.id`, then do a `project` and then do a `match` for that `test` field created. Would it be the same performance if I just do a `project` without a `match` first?